# php message passing with query string between pages

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP after logout send a query string from logout.php in header like `header("location:login.php?call=logout");` and on login page i got that call query string variable to show message on login page that `you are logged out` or etc.

But if i will directly go to `login.php?call=logout` link then same you are logout messgage will appear. but no logout process followed at this time.

How could i get rid from this problem.

if direct url `login.php?call=logout` passed then no log out message should displayed.

**logout.php**

```
<?php

header("location:login.php?call=logout");

?>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php

if($_GET['call']=='logout'){ echo "you are logged out.";}
?>
```

Comment: Um, don't display the message unless you actually perform the logout process?

Comment: yes john. if direct url pass then no message should display

Comment: @user When are you going to ever "pass the URL directly" to anyone, what would the harm be, and is that worth implementing a more complex solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your messsage to session. Example:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = 'Some message';
header("location: login.php");
exit;

// login.php
if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is that *actually* a problem worth solving? It's the easiest mechanism to display a message and unless you link to `login.php?call=logout` from anywhere else, nobody should ever get into this situation to begin with.
2. To "verify" that the message should actually be displayed you need to keep state server-side. Typically you'd use a session (even without logged in user) to store the information that a message should be displayed on that page.

Comment: yes this is problem ... and you want to say that i need to store messages in session on server side.?

Comment: Yes. In some way or another, the server will have to remember to display that message, and display it only once (i.e. don't display it unless there's a flag in the session to display it).